# buttons inside carousel-inner not clickable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using this [bootstrap3 template](http://demo.bootstraptor.com/landing_page_bs3/index2.htm#)
and I have noticed that any button inside the carousel of the first sliding block like:

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" href="#" title="">Sign up now!</a>
```

is not clickable unless you click on a small area in the button which is on the left border.
I am not sure what's happening here, the Event Listeners are registered correctly from the code and can't really find the issue.
Maybe is some weird styling bug?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button is being covered by the `<ol class="carousel-indicators">` as you can see here:

[image: Button being covered by HTML element]

Only the left portion, which is not covered by that element is clickable.  To fix this edit your CSS, change the width on `#carousel-example-generic1 .carousel-indicators` from 30% to 10%.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because for my div.carousel-item selector I had z-index of -1. Removed this line and buttons started working fine.